# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I added as Service Reference the below webservice and I uncheck the property 'Reuse type in all referenced assemblies'.

Here is the endpoint connection in the app.config:

```
<endpoint address="http://address-of-the-webservice/servicename.asmx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap"
                contract="WebService.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap" />
```

But still, if I try this:

```
ServiceSoapClient soapClient = new ServiceSoapClient();
```

I do get:

```
{"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WebService.ServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. 

This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."}
```

What I have done wrong? Thanks

Comment: In your code example, the endpoint ends with `/.asmx`. Did you just remove the service name for the example or is it really like this in your configuration file?

Comment: I just removed the service name as it is just an example

Comment: Doesn't the `contract` attribute accept an interface instead of a concrete implementation?

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm am a newbie in working with web services, but I did add other web services in the same way ( with a concrete implementation for the contract attr. ) and they work...

Comment: You should add a web reference, not a service reference, as this is clearly a ASMX service.